# NVRM: Xid: 79, GPU has fallen off the bus

Tags: power-supply, crash, power, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I am trying to do some deep-learning on my GeForce GTX 980 Ti GPU. I have a 658W power supply, but when I start running TensorFlow, I get the following error in dmesg:

```
[  158.598263] ata2: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
[  158.598268] ata2: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[  158.598271] ata2: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
[  158.598277] ata2: hard resetting link
[  159.602605] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-e29ec6c5-5146-95c4-f09c-68b96546640b
[  159.602609] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 79, GPU has fallen off the bus.

[  159.602613] NVRM: GPU at 0000:01:00.0 has fallen off the bus.
[  159.602623] NVRM: A GPU crash dump has been created. If possible, please run
               NVRM: nvidia-bug-report.sh as root to collect this data before
               NVRM: the NVIDIA kernel module is unloaded.
[  164.230199] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  164.237244] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  164.237248] ata2: EH complete
```

It seems like a small power surge which throws down my hard drive and graphical card. So I wonder, maybe I could ramp up my GPU slowly, so that it starts using more and more power in a slower manner so that it does not create this surge?

I use Ubuntu 16.04.1 with 4.8.0-34-generic kernel, with 375.26 nvidia kernel version.

```
nvidia-smi 
Tue Feb  7 15:02:47 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.26                 Driver Version: 375.26                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 980 Ti  Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   42C    P0    56W / 275W |      0MiB /  6077MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried connecting the GPU to its own power supply (older 750W which I cannot use directly on this mother board), but a similar thing happens:

```
[   81.865432] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-e29ec6c5-5146-95c4-f09c-68b96546640b
[   81.865437] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 79, GPU has fallen off the bus.

[   81.865474] NVRM: GPU at 0000:01:00.0 has fallen off the bus.
[   81.865484] NVRM: A GPU crash dump has been created. If possible, please run
               NVRM: nvidia-bug-report.sh as root to collect this data before
               NVRM: the NVIDIA kernel module is unloaded.
```

And the extra power supply turns off. So it seems they really do not like when GPU gets activated.

Comment: same problem. hard drive comes back quickly, graphics card stays dead

Comment: *"It seems like a small power surge..."* -- Seems like you're making a WAG without any corroboration.  Hence you're asking an XY question.  Did you even try collecting the crash dump for a bug report?  The odds are that this issue has nothing to do with power. I.E. see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-rhel-fedora-linux-nvidia-nvrm-gpu-fallen-off-bus/

Comment: Because I do have the newest driver, pretty recent kernel, I tried the persistence mode. And because there is also ATA issues at the same time. This is why I am guessing that it is a power surge. Because I tried mostly everything else I could imagine. But feel free to propose other things to try.

Comment: And yes, I collected the crash dump, but I can only send it to Nvidia. It is not really useful for me. It seems they encode/encrypt it in some way.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with Titan X Pascal cards. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I gave up for now on it.

Comment: I observed this message in the logs after an ESD (static shock) happened when I touched my computer's chassis.  Also, one of my hard drives fell off my RAID6 array noting SATA errors in `dmesg` kernel logs and `mdadm` started rebuilding.  After a reboot, the Nvidia card came back and worked fine.  The hard drive also worked fine, but I had to manually re-add it back into the RAID6 array with `mdadm`.
So, this issue may have different causes, but in my case it was caused by something electrical in nature (digital logic ground reference voltage had a transient spike, causing glitches).

Answer (score 4):

As per [Xid errors list](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/) (check [PDF](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/XID_Errors.pdf)), the error 79 (*GPU has fallen off the bus*) can be related to variety of things such as driver or hardware issue, system memory corruption, bus error or thermal issue (overheating).

Run *NVIDIA X Server Settings* app (which comes with the drivers) and check the temperature, graphic clock, performance levels and GPU utilization levels.

The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180342/55075) (based on this original [thread](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/957456/geforce-drivers/gtx-1080-throwing-bad-tlp-pcie-bus-errors/post/4969345/#4969345)), suggests to disable PCI-E ASPM ([Active State Power Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_State_Power_Management)) by changing boot params to `pcie_aspm=off` (it [forcibly disables PCIe ASPM](https://serverfault.com/q/226319/130437)).

Related bug report: [GPU has fallen off the bus](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1048032/gpu-has-fallen-off-the-bus/).

Comment: this didn't work for my case, but system was more stable, actually I only started X via startx and after those 3 main windows appeared I switched to other terminal console ctrl+alt Fx and logged in, it was not stable for about 10-15 minutes (for first time), but when I switched back to X ctrl+alt+f7, crash appeared.

Answer (score 0):

How I resolved it definitely not the best way but it got the job done and now I don't see this issue.
Actually this issue can be caused by multiple reasons and *NOBODY* has a definite fix. I've tried lots of suggestions and nothing helped.
Open `NVIDIA` app on Ubuntu, disable NVIDIA support and switch to Intel graphics management, it will be more power-efficient and won't cause this issue. Most of the development work developers do on Linux does not require much of GPU, so if you do, put the laptop on the charge, enable NVIDIA from the app, do your work and finally when the job gets done switch to Intel again. This is turn around I'm following at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem on Dell Precision M6700. The solution was simple, although it took me ages to come up with it: taking the battery out (and no - I was not using the battery - the laptop was connected at all times to the power supply).

The idea came up when reading that the error "Xid: 79, GPU has fallen off the bus" can happen also with relation to power supply issues. Apparently, the battery does not operate correctly, and probably this was the issue.

Later on I found out that adding pcie_aspm=off to GRUB does the trick as well (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/868321/gpu-has-fallen-off-the-bus-nvidia).